# How to route HTTPS URLs through a virtual environment

Tags: nginx, routing, https, docker, apache2

I’m having trouble setting up secure routing in an virtual environment.
All HTTP requests to both the **website** and the **REST API** work fine.
The certificate is provided by the company I work for and is a wildcard certificate for our domain.
My problem is the location of the certificate, which is not accessible to me.
I have tried to configure SSL in many places, but it only works partially.

To try out the routes, I use Postman and a regular browser (Chrome).
I can successfully visit the web pages, log in, send requests with JSON to the REST API.
All URLs start with `http://`.
When I do the exact same with but with `https://`, the browser shows the website is insecure. Postman also shows that there was an error connecting to the URL. This does not happen with `http://`.

The setup looks like this:
[The setup of my virtual system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4QHF.png)

A **gateway** server works as an entry point to multiple virtual machines. My application runs on one of them. The gateway runs **apache2** to facilitate routing to all virtual machines it hosts.
Also, it is the handler of SSL related matters for all virtual environments.

I’m developing a web application in PHP based on the Symfony framework.
In order to implement continuous integration with this application, we run the application in a **Docker** instance.
After a successful build in Jenkins, a script makes a new Docker image start.
The Docker image runs a **Nginx server** that hosts my application.

I have tried to configure the certificate in my Nginx config and in the apache2 config.
Both without a successful outcome.
I found out that a wildcard certificate does not apply to sub-subdomains.
Therefor `my-app.development.mycompany.com` will not work, I assume.
Changing the URLs to `development.mycompany.com/my-app/` was unsuccessful, 
because the PHP application picked up on the `/my-app/` part.
This caused problems for the application’s routing specifics and blocks other virtual machines’ applications.

I would like to understand how to configure the apache2 host to handle SSL.
To be able to develop more applications in this virtual environment in the future, I want to set this up so that HTTPS is covered for all virtual machines.
Why does this setup work for HTTP, but not for HTTPS?

The entry point’s virtual host config can be found below

```
    <VirtualHost *:444>
        ServerName development.mycompany.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate_bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
        #RewriteEngine on
        ProxyPreserveHost On
 
        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
 
        #ProxyPass /my-app/ http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
        #ProxyPassReverse /my-app/ http://my-app.developmenet.mycompany.com$
 
                ProxyPass / http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
                ProxyPassReverse / https://my-app.development.mycompany.com:444/
 
        #<Location />
        #        ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
        #        #ProxyPassReverse https://development.mycompany.com:444
        #        ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
        #</Location>
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName my-app.development.mycompany.com
                <Proxy *>
                               Order Deny,Allow
                               Allow from all
                </Proxy>
                <Location />
                               ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
 
                               #ProxyPass http://172.30.1.105:80/
                               #ProxyPassReverse http://172.30.1.105:80/
                </Location>
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName jenkins.my-app.development.mycompany.com
        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                               ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:86/
                               ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:86/
 
                #ProxyPass http://172.30.1.105:86/
                #ProxyPassReverse http://172.30.1.105:86/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName my-app.development.mycompany.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate_bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
 
        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName development.mycompany.com/my-app
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate_bundle.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.key
 
        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName development.mycompany.com/my-app
        <Proxy *>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-app.development.mycompany.com:80/
 
                #ProxyPass http://172.30.1.105:80/
                #ProxyPassReverse http://172.30.1.105:80/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Nginx configuration looks like this

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 444 ssl;
    server_name development.mycompany.com;
    root /var/www/my-app/web;
    client_max_body_size 4048M;

    location / {
         # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
         # try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
         index app.php;
         try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
        #internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/my_app_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my_app_access.log;
}
```

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: So.... what is the issue? I don't think you have clearly identified what is actually happening. Step away from the problem for a minute and think about it from an outsider's perspective. You've got all kinds of details and I cant tell what problem you're even having. An "I click this, and I see this" detail would be more helpful. Error messages, etc.

Comment: I've added some lines about what I see when trying out the routes. Hope this is of any help.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to make it more precise and easier to understand. You can include all the detail, but at least make the first paragraph so it's easy for people to understand what your problem is and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete chrome cache by opening dev tools then hit the 3 dots in the top right hand corner of dev tools and choose settings,  inside settings choose Disable cache (while DevTools is open) then close the settings,  now go to the "i" in chrome and click it, then remove any cookies associated with your website. Then click on your website and press Ctrl + f5 this will hard refresh the page.  if you still have not https then another process of elimination is to open the website in a tool like Gtmetrics and use the https domain this will give you an error if https is not working. The next step to try is mixed content, check your page source and search for HTTP: if you find then you have mixed content and you will need to find where the HTTP requests come from.  Make sure the URLs in the proxy pass are correct with backslashes and make sure your certificate is a wildcard or you are using multiple certificates for all domains and subdomains.  that's a basic checklist.  A bypass for your problems would be to use a CDN like cloudflare which gives free SSL connection and will work out of the box. Cloudflare will also speed up your website and protect against DDoS attacks which is on the rise. You just have to rewrite the URLs from HTTP to https, but really without the full story, it's all I can suggest at the moment. I hope you find your answer within the suggestions.